# Effective way to notate triplets

Tags: notation, rhythm, lilypond, tuplet

I was directed by [America Luke](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/55316/american-luke) to this forum site. I hope this is the correct place.

I have a score with a lot of triplets. It's awkward to write always `\times 2/3 {c16 d e} \times 2/3 {d e f}`.

Since the `\times` causes not only the duration scaling but also the bracket length you can't use

```
\times 2/3 {c16 d e   d e f}.
```

How can this done more efficiently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's worth pointing out that as of LilyPond 2.17.11, you can write

```
\tuplet 3/2 8 {c16 d e d e f}
```

and get 3:2 tuplets in groups of duration 8 (in this case, two groups of three tuplets each).  This is basically the same as temporarily overriding `tupletSpannerDuration`.

Answer (score 7):

I think that your problem isn't intrinsically with the triplets, but rather with [controlling beams](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.16/Documentation/notation/beams); one approach is to manually set the beams:

Running lilypond 2.16 on

```
{
\times 2/3 {c16^"Two 3-note phrases"  d e } \times 2/3 { d e f } r4 r2

\times 2/3 { c16^"Manual Beaming" [d e] d [e f] } r4 r2

\set tupletSpannerDuration = #(ly:make-moment 1 8)
\times 2/3 { c16^"Moment & Manual Beaming" [d e] d [e f] } r4 r2

}
```

yields this [image: lilypond output]

The square brackets in the lilypond file indicate the beams in the same manner as parentheses indicate slurs.

Comment: Cool!  Question: shouldn't the "one six note phrase" really have a "6" over it to indicate the number of notes in one beat?

Comment: Yeah, the "six note prhase" looks odd, and possibly ambiguous; c.f. (http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12655/notating-6-or-more-triplets-with-a-single-bar)

Comment: Well, all your examples show some inadequate pictures. First (as my example) has correct brackets but wrong beaming. Second and third has a bracket over multiple triplets. I write a piece with triplet over several staves. (as at page 4 of http://javanese.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/5/50/IMSLP248772-PMLP403277-ETAHoffmann_Harp_Quintet_score.pdf) It's not a pleasure to find somewhere the bracket number instead about the triplet itself. Isn't there an effective way to write triplets.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft use `\times 4/6` instead, and lilypond will even try to infer the best beaming as available.

Comment: Yes I know that I can start and stop the beams with []. But that isn't what I am looking for. Can't I tell Lilypond to write 100 triplets with _automatic_ beaming?

Answer (score 7):

You have to specify the property tupletSpannerDuration to get several tuplets using only one `\times` command:

```
\set tupletSpannerDuration = #(ly:make-moment 1 8)
\times 2/3 {c16 d e d e f }
```

See LilyPond [Documentation](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.16/Documentation/notation/writing-rhythms#tuplets) for more on this.

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is no need to restrict the contents of one brace to 3 notes only, so for consecutive triplets, as in your example, a minor compression can be:

```
\times 2/3 {c16 d e d e f}
```

Comment: Ok, since the OP claimed this fouls up the bracket length, can someone post the actual pdfs this code generates?

Answer (score 1):

A better looking grouping:

```
\relative c' {
  \override TupletBracket.bracket-visibility = #'if-no-beam
  \times 2/3 { c16 c \set stemRightBeamCount = #1 c }
  \times 2/3 { \set stemLeftBeamCount = #1 c c c }  
}
```

yields this:

[image]